# How to automate appregnew in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, deployment

I need to register a Provider hosted app in a site collection. It is possible to do it manually by using appregnew.aspx page. Is there anyway to do the same using C#/Powershell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it myself. You can register the app in office 365 tenancy[SharePoint Online] using the below Azure AD MSOLService PS Script.

```
$clientID="7c6cbd92-073b-4bc9-9d4a-fc27749f340b";
$newClientSecret = "p/zEuKBqkZRQsz6yRpOafj2f6zZdnQYvONatGWj0N0M=";
$appDomain="Yourdomain.azurewebsites.net";
$appUrl="https://Yourdomain.azurewebsites.net/";
$appName="Your App Name"
$servicePrincipalName = @("$clientID/$appDomain")
$dtStart = [System.DateTime]::Now
$dtEnd = $dtStart.AddYears(10)

Connect-MsolService 
New-MsolServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalNames $servicePrincipalName -AppPrincipalId $clientID -DisplayName $appName -Type Symmetric -Usage Verify -Value $newClientSecret -Addresses (New-MsolServicePrincipalAddresses -Address $appUrl) -StartDate $dtStart  –EndDate $dtEnd
New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $clientId -Type Symmetric -Usage Sign -Value $newClientSecret -StartDate $dtStart  –EndDate $dtEnd
New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $clientId -Type Password -Usage Verify -Value $newClientSecret -StartDate $dtStart  –EndDate $dtEnd
```

Comment: Hi, is there any way to do this in C#/CSOM?

Comment: There is no such option to do this using CSOM. Also, this does not come under SharePoint this is related to Azure AD.

Comment: ok. Thanks. But it will create a new app principal in SharePoint Online right?

Comment: Yes, it will create new app principal in SharePoint online as it is bonded to Azure AD.

Comment: does this work for trusting an app on certain sharepoint site? thanks

Comment: You cannot automate app trusting process in SP Online.

Answer (score 2):

Please read this link:
[Register SharePoint Add-ins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/register-sharepoint-add-ins)

According to this link you can also Register the add-in through the Seller Dashboard. It's great option if you're going to use your add-in in more than one SharePoint tenant or farm. **Publication in store is not required.** **This way you can choose a three-year valid secret key.**

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not, because the manual granting of consent is part of the app model architecture.